# Xamarin project won't build after moving folder path

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created a new Xamarin Forms application using the latest Xamarin Studio for OSX and I have build errors caused by the following:
1. Moving the project on my local machine
2. Putting the project in source control and restoring to another machine

If I type xbuild in the terminal I can see that my project is referencing a file path from my other computer (now on the 2nd computer after restoring from source control).

I cannot find the file path information in any of the files inside of the Xamarin Forms solution so I can't tell where it is picking up this file path from!!

> /Users/x/Documents/Work/Wire%20Mobile/src/Wire.sln: error : Could not
>   find a part of the path "/Users/x/Documents/Work/Wire
>   Mobile/src/Wire.sln".

Can anyone advise how i can store a project in source control without having hard links to the file path that it used to reside on in the old machine please? Also I've tried this on two projects now, could it be a bug in Xamarin?

Comment: Never mind I just answered my own question, it was the %20 in the file path .... the xbuild doesn't support file paths with %20 in them. Visual Studio Team Services is quite fond of these types of file paths however!

Comment: *.sln & *.csproj files usually use relative paths, not full.  You should be able to edit them using a text editor to verify this (and fix if necessary)

Comment: If you have an answer, post it as one! It is [explicitly allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

the xbuild doesn't support file paths with %20 in them. Visual Studio Team Services is quite fond of these types of file paths however!

removed %20 from the path and now it works fine.

also affects Unity projects and Visual Studio for Mac projects.